# To go in a new line

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript method:

```
function mousemove() {
        var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
            i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
            d0 = data[i - 1],
            d1 = data[i],
            d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0,
            ix = bisectDate(datax, x0, 1), // faccio ora la stessa cosa per datax
            d0x = datax[ix - 1],
            d1x = datax[ix],
            dx = x0 - d0x.date > d1x.date - x0 ? d1x : d0x;
        focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(dx.date) + "," + 0 + ")");
        focus.select("text").text(function() { if (dx.price == 0) return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + ": \n" + d.price; else return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + " - " + d.price + " - " + dx.price; });
        focus.select(".x-hover-line").attr("y2", y(0));  // il punto di inizio della retta è l'altezza dell'area in quella preciso punto, mentre il punto di fine viene indicato tramite y2 e diciamo quanto la retta deve essere lunga, scrivo y(dx.price) perchè voglio l'altezza in pollici
        focus.select(".y-hover-line").attr("x2", width);
}
```

In this line in `": \n"` I want to go in a new line:

```
focus.select("text").text(function() { if (dx.price == 0) return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + ": \n" + d.price; else return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + " - " + d.price + " - " + dx.price; });
```

I tried with '\n' but it does not work

Comment: Did you try "<br>" instead?

Comment: If this is writing to HTML then `<br>` should be used instead of the newline character. That is why it is not being observed - '\n' is not valid in HTML.

Comment: Can you show entire line?

Comment: i guess you want to add an "<br>" tag at this point do you

Comment: focus.select("text").text(function() { if (dx.price == 0) return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] +  ":" + <br> +d.price; else return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + " - " + d.price + " - " + dx.price; }); does not work

Comment: @Mario you didn't put " " before '<br>' try this: focus.select("text").text(function() { if (dx.price == 0) return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + ": " + "<br>" + d.price; else return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + " - " + d.price + " - " + dx.price; });

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in question to

```
focus.select("text").html(function() { if (dx.price == 0) return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + ": <br>" + d.price; else return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + " - " + d.price + " - " + dx.price; });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the `.text` call. ProEvilz is correct

Comment: does not work, It does not print anymore <br> but does not go to new line

Answer (score 0):

As other members have suggested, use a `<br>` tag instead.

edit: Since we're now injecting `html`, we need to change `.text()` to `.html()`

```
focus.select("text").html(function() { if (dx.price == 0) {return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + ": <br>" + d.price;} else { return monthNames[d.date.getMonth()] + " - " + d.price + " - " + dx.price; }});
```

Comment: @Mario I've updated my answer. Since you were using `.text()`, it would only insert text and not `HTML`.

Comment: does not work, It does not print anymore <br> but does not go to new line

Comment: @Mario In fact, show me the output of the function, like th actual html output?